# Merge 2 resulting vectors into 1 data frame using R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, dplyr

I have a df like this

```
Month <- c('JAN','JAN','JAN','JAN','FEB','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','MAY') 
Category <- c('A','A','B','C','A','E','B','D','E','F')
Year <- c(2014,2015,2015,2015,2014,2013,2015,2014,2015,2013)
Number_Combinations <- c(3,2,3,4,1,3,6,5,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Month ,Category,Year,Number_Combinations)
df

  Month Category Year Number_Combinations
1  JAN        A 2014                   3
2  JAN        A 2015                   2
3  JAN        B 2015                   3
4  JAN        C 2015                   4
5  FEB        A 2014                   1
6  FEB        E 2013                   3
7  MAR        B 2015                   6
8  APR        D 2014                   5
9  MAY        E 2015                   1
10 MAY        F 2013                   1
```

I have another df that I got from the above dataframe with a condition

```
df1 <- subset(df,Number_Combinations > 2)
df1

  Month Category Year Number_Combinations
1  JAN        A 2014                   3
3  JAN        B 2015                   3
4  JAN        C 2015                   4
6  FEB        E 2013                   3
7  MAR        B 2015                   6
8  APR        D 2014                   5
```

Now I want to create a table reporting the month, the total number of rows for the month in df and the total number of for the month in df1

**Desired Output would be**

```
  Month Number_Month_df Number_Month_df1
1   JAN               4                3
2   FEB               2                1
3   MAR               1                1
4   APR               1                1
5   MAY               2                0
```

While I used `table(df)` and `table(df1)` and tried merging but not getting the desired result. Could someone please help me in getting the above dataframe?

Comment: TRy `res1 <- df %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(Number_Month_df=n()); res2 <- df1 %>% group_by(Month) %>% summarise(Number_Month_df1=n()); left_join(res1, res2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the `table` of the 'Month' column from both 'df' and 'df1', convert to 'data.frame' (`as.data.frame`), `merge` by the 'Var1', and change the column names accordingly.

```
 res <- merge(as.data.frame(table(df$Month)), 
             as.data.frame(table(df1$Month)), by='Var1')
 colnames(res) <- c('Month', 'Number_Month_df', 'Number_Month_df1')
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks @akrun.

Answer (score 1):

```
res <- data.frame(Number_Month_df=sort(table(df$Month),T),
                  Number_Month_df1=sort(table(df1$Month),T))
res$Month <- rownames(res)
```

Comment: Great solution but I will just stick to not having months as rownames. Thank you so much @nongkrong